# Table Captions with no Separator between heading and Table number (Word 2016)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a document which I would like the tables to follow the following format.

Section 1.1 would have Tables 1.1A, 1.1B etc.

However, Word does not have a 'no separator' option, so the tables have to be formatted as 1.1.A or 1.1-A. neither of which fit the style guide I need to follow.

Is there any way to remove the need for a separator without having to change every table caption manually? because I have over 600 tables (it is a technical appendix).

I am using Word 2016

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing space in caption](https://superuser.com/q/1312506/150988) — but it isn’t answered.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no easy way to add a separator in the list. However there is a workaround you can use.

First select a separator you don't use anywhere else (I would guess the underscore) and display the fields codes (Alt+F9), then do a search and replace (Ctrl+H) from '}_{' to '}{'.

You can then hide the fields codes (Alt+F9) and update your fields at will since Word only update what's between the braces {}. Note that new captions won't have the 'no separator' formatting.

Comment: I tried this but I cannot find replace the }_{ because the { characters are in the field code while the _ is not. also if i add a new table caption it messes with all of the others which go form '1.1A' to '1.11.1_A'. i guess word just needs a separator for some reason. thanks for the suggestion though, it sounded like it would have worked