# Removing space in caption (MS Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am adding a custom caption label in Word 2016. Let's say I call it `Table S`, pertaining to all the supplementary tables. To do so, I go to `Insert Caption` > `New Label`, and type it there.

Thus, new labels are called `Table S 1`, `Table S 2`, and so on. But, I dont want that little `[space]` between `S` and the `number`. I'd like to have it `Table S1`, `Table S2`.

How can you automatically number these in Word, but without the space between `S` and `[number]`?

Comment: Probably not possible from interface. Just insert "Table S 1"... and when the text is ready replace "Table S " with "Table S" (without space).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table captions with no separator between heading and table number](https://superuser.com/q/1256547/150988) –– but it doesn’t have an answer that works.